# Sharepoint designer workflow wont add item to another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

in a sharepoint 365 environment.
I have list with student names.

I'would like to add a workflow so that when a new student is added, another list will add an new entry starting with that student name as a link to the first table.

I get confused by sharepoint designer i click add list item.
Select the seccond list, but it seams not to create the link. every option i tried with add list item, so far failed.

Comment: SharePoint will use permissions of the User for the workflow.  Make sure your permissions are correct for the User in both lists.  [Here's another related question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92315/under-what-permission-does-workflow-run)

Comment: Well i'm basically the owner of the whole site.. so i should have permissions right, i'm the admin